# How to fix 'fs module not found' error when using Langchain document loaders in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, artificial-intelligence, langchain

I am working on an AI project. I am using Langchain and Next.js 13.

I am trying to use the document loaders in langchain to load my PDF, however when I call a loader eg

`import { PDFLoader } from "langchain/document_loaders/fs/pdf";`

Immediately I get an error:

`fs module not found`

What I expect:

As per langchain documentation, this should not occur as it states that the APIs support Next.js enviroment.

What I have tried

I have tried using a package(pdf.js) to handle PDF file upload and parsing, but I get an error with this as well.

How can I use langchains document loaders in Next.js?

Answer (score 2):

I finally understand the issue here.

I was calling it in the browser context but once I moved my code to the API routes(Node) environment, everything worked as expected.

Comment: I think you followed the steps in ChatGPT tutorial on Youtube. I've the same issue. To which folder did you move files in `lib`?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question.

Comment: and what about this ??https://js.langchain.com/docs/integrations/document_loaders/web_loaders/pdf

langchain support web environment but still getting same error `fs not found`